# How to debug an access violation in atexit

Tags: python, python-2.7

A very large application I am working has a segfault when I shut it down. If I use faulthandler, it says there is an access violation in atexit

```
Current thread 0x00000a8c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24 in _run_exitfuncs
Windows exception: access violation

Current thread 0x00000a8c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24 in _run_exitfuncs
Segmentation fault
```

That really doesn't tell me much. When I debug through the code, it goes all the way through main and out. The debugger won't step anymore after that, even though the program isn't all the way done yet. If I let it continue, it just does the segfault and doesn't show me anything.

I imagine it is some library we are using, but how to identify it?

Comment: You can print `atexit._exithandlers` to see what functions have been registered - hopefully there aren't too many of them.  Or, you can invoke `atexit._run_exitfuncs()` to actually run the functions, while your debugger is still active.

Comment: @jasonharper [(<built-in function __cleanup>, (), {}), (<function shutdown at 0x014212B0>, (), {}), (<function _exit_function at 0x017EC070>, (), {}), (<built-in function App_CleanUp>, (), {}), (<function stoptrace at 0x017D4070>, (), {}), (<function shutdown at 0x032E4330>, (), {})] ... Unfortunately, it doesn't tell me much. I guess these shutdown functions are in libraries somewhere.

Comment: `[f.func_globals['__name__'] for f, _, _ in atexit._exithandlers]` should give you the module names for each of those functions.

Comment: @jasonharper 'AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'func_globals''